# a coin is flipped twice what is the conditional probability that both flips result in heads given that the first flip does

Tags: probability

a coin is flipped twice what is the conditional probability that both flips result in heads given that the first flip does
im stuck but i know that the cases for throwing twice are, HT HH TH TT

Comment: It's $\frac12$.

Comment: how did you know its half

Comment: hey im trying to work out this question and all im asking is help please

Comment: You have to divide the probability that both results in heads by the probability that the first flip does.

Answer (score 1):

> I am stuck but I know that the cases for throwing twice are, HT HH TH TT

More, if the coin is fair, then you also know each outcome has the same probability.

Now, how many outcomes are possible under the condition that the first coin shows `head`?   Would these not still each have the same (conditional)probability?   Now, the sum of the (conditional)probability of all possible outcomes equals one, so...

$~\\~\\~\\~$

---

… or you may use the definition of conditional probability.